# Can i search about some files stored in google bucket inside my react app?

Tags: reactjs, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have a reaction app that stores some files in the google cloud " Bucket " so I wonder if I can search for some files stored in a 'Bucket' inside my React app which i don't know what is the exact name of it, Can I do that?
If yes, in what way?
if you have any tutorial, i will be appreciate.

What i mean by search is this list and filter:

[image]
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean "search"? If you already know the name you want to find, you can try to open the file.  If it fails, it either doesn't exist or you don't have permission to open it.

If you want to see if it exists before opening, this should point you in the right direction:

```
from google.cloud import storage
client = storage.Client()

blobs = client.list_blobs('your_default_bucket')

filenames = []
for blob in blobs:
    filenames.append(blob.name)
    
print(filenames)

file_exists = 'my_file.csv' in filenames

print(f"file_exists: {file_exists}")
```

Comment: thanks for help, i updated my question, i mean when i am not sure about the exact name of file, so i need some files suggestion depend on what i wrote in search bar.

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of cases it's better to use 3rd part libraries. One that could suit your need is [react-autosuggest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-autosuggest).

basic usage:

```
import Autosuggest from 'react-autosuggest';
 
// Imagine you have a list of languages that you'd like to autosuggest.
const files = [
  {
    name: 'file1'
  },
  {
    name: 'file2'
  },
  ...
];
 
// Teach Autosuggest how to calculate suggestions for any given input value.
const getSuggestions = value => {
  const inputValue = value.trim().toLowerCase();
  const inputLength = inputValue.length;
 
  return inputLength === 0 ? [] : languages.filter(lang =>
    lang.name.toLowerCase().slice(0, inputLength) === inputValue
  );
};
 
// When suggestion is clicked, Autosuggest needs to populate the input
// based on the clicked suggestion. Teach Autosuggest how to calculate the
// input value for every given suggestion.
const getSuggestionValue = suggestion => suggestion.name;
 
// Use your imagination to render suggestions.
const renderSuggestion = suggestion => (
  <div>
    {suggestion.name}
  </div>
);
 
class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
 
    // Autosuggest is a controlled component.
    // This means that you need to provide an input value
    // and an onChange handler that updates this value (see below).
    // Suggestions also need to be provided to the Autosuggest,
    // and they are initially empty because the Autosuggest is closed.
    this.state = {
      value: '',
      suggestions: []
    };
  }
 
  onChange = (event, { newValue }) => {
    this.setState({
      value: newValue
    });
  };
 
  // Autosuggest will call this function every time you need to update suggestions.
  // You already implemented this logic above, so just use it.
  onSuggestionsFetchRequested = ({ value }) => {
    this.setState({
      suggestions: getSuggestions(value)
    });
  };
 
  // Autosuggest will call this function every time you need to clear suggestions.
  onSuggestionsClearRequested = () => {
    this.setState({
      suggestions: []
    });
  };
 
  render() {
    const { value, suggestions } = this.state;
 
    // Autosuggest will pass through all these props to the input.
    const inputProps = {
      placeholder: 'Type a programming language',
      value,
      onChange: this.onChange
    };
 
    // Finally, render it!
    return (
      <Autosuggest
        suggestions={suggestions}
        onSuggestionsFetchRequested={this.onSuggestionsFetchRequested}
        onSuggestionsClearRequested={this.onSuggestionsClearRequested}
        getSuggestionValue={getSuggestionValue}
        renderSuggestion={renderSuggestion}
        inputProps={inputProps}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

check a demo [here also](https://react-autosuggest.js.org/)

Comment: thanks for your help, can this library deal with files stored in my cloud not in local storage?

Comment: to reach your data you need some kind of backend server that provide these data to your react app. you cannot get these kind of data directly from the client "react".

Comment: I costumed a small server to upload file from client to cloud inside react app using {Express API, fetch API}, but i don't use any backend tool to store data, so can i add something to my server to search in cloud or i can't? because i don't want use another database with cloud, Sorry to bother you, my knowledge of the field is simple.